# Resolve absolute path to Documentation Notebook

Tags: files-and-directories, documentation, undocumented

We can easily create clickable hyperlinks for Documentation pages like the following:

```
{URL["paclet:ref/Set"], Hyperlink["paclet:ref/Set"]}
```

[image: screenshot]

But how can I resolve such an URL into the absolute path to the Documentation's Notebook?

I expected that `Information` can do it, but it doesn't:

```
Information[URL["paclet:ref/Set"], "AbsolutePath"]
```

> ```
> "paclet:ref/Set"
> ```

Note that in version 13 the standard path to Documentation files has changed, and now by default they are located in a hidden folder in the user's profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update: `` Documentation`ResolveLink ``

Tracing `NotebookOpen[uri]` with `TraceInternal -> True` reveals a call to `` Documentation`ResolveLink `` function which actually resolves the Documentation URIs:

```
Documentation`ResolveLink["paclet:ref/Set"]
```

> ```
> "C:\\Users\\APopkov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Wolfram Research\\Documentation.en-us\\13.0\\Documentation\\English\\System\\ReferencePages\\Symbols\\Set.nb"
> ```

---

### Original answer

One working solution is to open the URI with `NotebookOpen` and then obtain the absolute path via `NotebookFileName`:

```
resolveNotebookPath[uri_] := 
 Module[{no = NotebookOpen[uri, Visible -> False], nfn}, 
  nfn = NotebookFileName[no]; NotebookClose[no]; nfn]
```

Example:

```
resolveNotebookPath["paclet:ref/Set"]
```

> ```
> "C:\\Users\\APopkov\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Wolfram Research\\Documentation.en-us\\13.0\\Documentation\\English\\System\\ReferencePages\\Symbols\\Set.nb"
> ```

Of course, it isn't a good method since it requires actually opening the Notebook, which may take substantial system resources and is potentially dangerous.