# How to get link for local documentation

Tags: documentation

If one evaluates `?GoochShading`, the output is some info about the function as well as links to its documentation:

[image: popup]

One can click the circled *i* or the Local » link to open the documentation for it.  How can I write that link which opens local docs in text or a `Hyperlink`?  I'm going to self answer about the Local » link, but is the circled *i* link the same?

Comment: Related: "[Resolve absolute path to Documentation Notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261376/280)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`WolframLanguageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html).

To get a formatted hyperlink.

```
doclink = WolframLanguageData["GoochShading"]["WolframDocumentationLink"]
```

To view the `InputForm`

```
InputForm[doclink]
```

> ```
> Hyperlink["GoochShading", "paclet:ref/GoochShading"]
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to use `FullForm` to see the link used in the `InformationData` result, but apparently that's not necessary: `Information[GoochShading,"Documentation"]` yields

```
<|
"Local" -> "paclet:ref/GoochShading", 
"Web" -> "http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GoochShading.html"
|>
```

and `Hyperlink@"paclet:ref/GoochShading"` works to open the docs.  Now I can both pester people to search the docs themselves, and actually point them to specific doc pages.