# Entire process of "hyperlink of paclet" to "location of real file"?

Tags: notebooks, files-and-directories, system, paclets, hyperlink

```
Hyperlink[AAAAA, "paclet:ref/ModularInverse"]
AAAAA
```

[image]

If I click `AAAAA`, then a tutorial notebook for ModularInverse.nb opens.
In other words, MMA opens following .nb file :

*C:\Users\ ((username)) \AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\13.1\Documentation\English\System\ReferencePages\Symbols\ModularInverse.nb*

In terms of results, MMA has converted the string

```
"paclet:ref/ModularInverse"
```

to

```
"C:\Users\ ((username)) \AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Wolfram Research\Documentation.en-us\13.1\Documentation\English\System\ReferencePages\Symbols\ModularInverse.nb"
```

I want to know the **detail** of above conversion process.(<- *This is the question*)

During the conversion, MMA may refered to some pre-exsting editable files(.nb or.m ...).

Comment: This question might have the answers: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/261376/9490

Comment: Thank you very much, half of the problem is solved. If we knew the "detail" of entire process, we could change the target(a location of .nb file) of "paclet:ref/ModularInverse", by editing some pre-exsiting .nb or .m ...